# Visual Studio C/C++ ucrtbased.dll Access Violation Writing Location

Tags: c, char, visual-studio-2015

I'm using Visual Studio Enterprise 2015, I've been getting this error :

```
Exception thrown at 0x00007FF8E19979A3 (ucrtbased.dll) in Assignment 1C.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x0000008836510000.
```

...whenever I use a char/string input, to the extent that this simple program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char name[40], chk;

    printf("What is your name?");
    scanf_s("%s", name);
    chk = getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

is still giving me the same error. I don't know what is causing it though I suspect it's something from the libraries I'm using or the actual compiler? Open for suggestions.

Comment: `scanf_s("%s", name);` **->** `scanf_s("%s", name,39);` You will need to specify size when using `%s` specifier in `scanf_s` .

Comment: I see. It worked. Do you specify the size in bytes or in locations in the array?

Comment: From MSDN `Unlike scanf and wscanf, scanf_s and wscanf_s require the buffer size to be specified for all input parameters of type c, C, s, S, or string control sets that are enclosed in []. The buffer size in characters is passed as an additional parameter immediately following the pointer to the buffer or variable.`

Comment: @ameyCU That was my same issue, too.  Many thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 1):

scanf_s() of argument is wrong.

scanf_s("%s", name, 40);
or
scanf_s("%s", name, _countof(name));

see also:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w40768et.aspx